# I am not able to use functions in keras on M1 Mac in R and it is asking me to install arm64e version of miniconda3. What to do?

Tags: r, keras, rstudio, apple-m1

> '''Error in py_initialize(config$python, config$libpython,
> config$pythonhome,  :
> /Users/abhiishekchugh/miniconda3/envs/r-reticulate/lib/libpython3.7m.dylib
>
> - dlopen(/Users/abhiishekchugh/miniconda3/envs/r-reticulate/lib/libpython3.7m.dylib,
>   0x000A): tried:
>   '/Users/abhiishekchugh/miniconda3/envs/r-reticulate/lib/libpython3.7m.dylib'
>   (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need
>   'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/libpython3.7m.dylib' (no such file)'''

This is the error I get everytime I use keras on M1 Mac as Miniconda3 doesn't have arm support apparently...
Is there any work around for this?
I am using this in the latest R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The current release of Tensorflow (2.7) does not support M1 Macs. However, there is a lot of on going work in this space. For the time being, until official support is available, Apple is providing a custom build of Tensorflow specifically for M1 Macs. You can install it by following the directions here: https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/

Once that is installed, you can point R at the custom installation by setting the environment variable `RETICULATE_PYTHON=/path/to/python/bin/python`.
For reference, you can also refer to the "Apple Silicon" section in https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tensorflow/versions/2.6.0/topics/install_tensorflow, or by typing `?tensorflow::install_tensorflow` at the R console.

Comment: I followed these exact instructions, but unfortunately I still get the same error.

Comment: Are you also running the arm64 build of R? This error can also occur if you have an x86 build of R running under rosetta.